# adb command to disable "Always ON" & "Lift to check phone" in Ambient display settings

Tags: android, adb

I would like to turn off the following two settings by adb command, does anyone know how to do it?

- Settings > Display > Ambient Display > Always ON
- Settings > Display > Ambient Display > Lift to check phone

I tried the command below and it appears to only disable wake up screen when there's a new notification:

```
adb shell settings put secure doze_enabled 0
```

Answer (score 4):

**To find out name of some system setting you can use this technique:**

1. Export all settings from the device:

```
    adb shell settings list global > global_before.txt
    adb shell settings list system > system_before.txt
    adb shell settings list secure > secure_before.txt
```

2. Change the wanted setting in Settings application
3. Export all settings from the device again:

```
    adb shell settings list global > global_after.txt  
    adb shell settings list system > system_after.txt  
    adb shell settings list secure > secure_after.txt
```

4. Compare the before/after files and the single change you will find will be your setting.

---

So, I found that you can turn off Lift to check phone with this command:

```
adb shell settings put system lift_to_wake 0
```

Second one you will find yourself as I don't know with what setting on my phone it corresponds to (my Settings app is organized differently).